# how to use facebook sdk to sign in on an Android phone?? (error= applicationID is null)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I can't figure out why I keep getting a null pointer exception ("applicationID cannot be null"). My code looks almost identical to this. The only part I don't use is the "welcome text"

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

I set up an app on the Facebook developers page and then define the ID in the manifest as meta-data, as instructed in the Facebook tutorials. more specifically, I define the app by including a reference to my strings (strings/appID), and in the strings.xml, I actually define the string (really long number). I'm pretty sure this part is correct!

I also added a reference to the "LoginActivity" class (located in the Facebook SD) to my own app's manifest, as suggested by this tutorial

do I need to pass the applicationID anywhere to the Session? that's the last thing I can think of but unfortunately I have not been successful

any help would be greatly appreciated. I really don't know what else to change so my app recognizes the applicationID!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I having similar problem. Do not put **appId** directly in manifest, place here only reference to **@strings**, and put id to **@strings**.
There problem with big integers in manifest, and **appId** looks as big integer.

Comment: Hi Ilya, good point. sorry for not clarifying. I am already doing what you suggested and have modified your answer. any other tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated though. thanks!

Comment: > do I need to pass the applicationID

No, I do not pass **applicationID** in code, only in manifest

Comment: hm, still no luck :( anyone else have any suggestions?